# v-show: Check if a models value equals an element's name

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, model, conditional-statements

I am struggling a bit with Vue.js right now. I have a select input element with multiple options. The value of each option is equal to another input element's name and I want to only display the input element with the name accroding to the selected value at a time.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedOption: ''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- This select ust always be visible! -->
  <select v-model="selectedOption">
    <option value="testInput1">testInput1</option>
    <option value="testInput2">testInput2</option>
    <option value="testInput3">testInput3</option>
    <option value="testInput4">testInput4</option>
  </select>
  <!-- The folling elements must be toggled based on the selection above -->
  <input type="text" name="testInput1" value="testInput1" v-show="selectedOption === this.name" />
  <input type="text" name="testInput2" value="testInput2" v-show="selectedOption === this.name" />
  <input type="text" name="testInput3" value="testInput3" v-show="selectedOption === this.name" />
  <select name="testInput4" v-show="selectedOption === this.name">
    <option value="0">Yes</option>
    <option value="1">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I guess it is because of the `this.name` code snippet inside the `v-show`, but I have no clue how to get the elements properties itself in the `v-show`. And yes I googled, but to be honest I have no real idea about what I should google here...

I guess there is a really simple solution, but I am still new to Vue...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check at `v-show` if `selectedOption` meets `value` of `<option>`. You can do it easily like this.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedOption: 'testInput1',
   
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- This select ust always be visible! -->
  <select v-model="selectedOption">
    <option value="testInput1">testInput1</option>
    <option value="testInput2">testInput2</option>
    <option value="testInput3">testInput3</option>
    <option value="testInput4">testInput4</option>
  </select>
  <!-- The folling elements must be toggled based on the selection above -->
  <input type="text" name="testInput1" value="testInput1" v-show="selectedOption === 'testInput1'" />
  <input type="text" name="testInput2" value="testInput2" v-show="selectedOption === 'testInput2'" />
  <input type="text" name="testInput3" value="testInput3" v-show="selectedOption === 'testInput3'" />
  <select name="testInput4" v-show="selectedOption === 'testInput4'">
    <option value="0">Yes</option>
    <option value="1">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```